# Do I need to use CloseHandle after creating a new process?

Tags: windows, winapi, visual-c++

I need to launch a separate process/application from a context menu; I'm using the function `launch_program` to do so. I **don't care** about the exit code from the created process once it terminates, I just want to be able to launch it. My question is: if the variables `startup_info` and `proc_info` are being passed by reference to `CreateProcess` am I able to use `CloseHandle` on them if I'm just going to return from the function to my Main Thread?

```
void launch_program()
{
    STARTUPINFO startup_info;
    PROCESS_INFORMATION proc_info;
    LPCSTR location = "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Internet Explorer\\iexplore.exe";

    ZeroMemory( &startup_info,sizeof(startup_info));
    startup_info.cb = sizeof(startup_info);
    ZeroMemory( &proc_info,sizeof(proc_info));

    CreateProcess(  location,
                    NULL,
                    NULL,
                    NULL,
                    FALSE,
                    0,
                    NULL,
                    NULL,
                    &startup_info,
                    &proc_info);

}
```

I used https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682512(v=vs.85).aspx for reference.

PS I just used Internet Explorer as a filler
[EDIT] For Completeness:

```
CloseHandle(proc_info.hProcess);
CloseHandle(proc_info.hThread);
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Yes, you can and should close those handles when you no longer need them, including right away if you'll never need them.

From the page you linked [Creating Processes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682512.aspx):

> The thread and process handles are created with full access rights, although access can be restricted if you specify security descriptors. **When you no longer need these handles, close them by using the CloseHandle function**.

---

*[ EDIT ]* To emphasize the `*should* close` part, which maybe isn't stated strongly enough in the docs, here is a quote from @RaymondChen's blog:

[Why do some process stay in Task Manager after they’ve been killed?](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20040723-00/?p=38363)

> After all the drivers have acknowledged the death of the process, the "meat" of the process finally goes away. All that remains is the "process object", which lingers until all handles to the process and all the threads in the process have been closed. (***You did remember to CloseHandle the handles returned in the PROCESS_INFORMATION structure that you passed to the CreateProcess function, didn't you?***)

Comment: I was just worried that if I closed those handles before the new process (IE in this case) exited, there would be issues with memory.

Comment: @pixel It doesn't matter *when* you close those handles. There would be issues if you *never* closed them. I edited my answer to make that point more clear.

Comment: @pixel Everything that dxiv has said here is correct, I just want to point out that calling `CloseHandle` to close a process (or thread) handle does *not* cause the process (or thread) to terminate. That's why it doesn't matter when you call `CloseHandle`.

Comment: @Cody Gray Do you know why Microsoft wanted those 2 variables (`STARTUPINFO` & `PROCESS_INFORMATION`) passed by reference instead of value? If I had designed it, I would pass by value because I don't know when the memory would be reassigned/potential race conditions.

Comment: @pixel Almost all structures in the Windows API are passed by pointer. It is a C API designed in the 1980s. As I understand (it was before my time), passing large structures by value just wasn't something you did back then. I guess compilers of the day couldn't handle it in an intelligent way. For the same reason, no functions return structures; they all pass read/write pointers. And of course, in the 1980s, no one was worried about multi-threaded race conditions. You cannot possibly have a race condition here with single-threaded code.

Comment: @pixel In addition to @CodyGray's good points, the `PROCESS_INFORMATION` parameter *must* be passed by reference, since it *returns* information back to the caller.

Comment: @pixel Also, passing by reference allows some rudimentary way of overloading or, lacking a better word, forward binary compatibility. Note in the docs that the `lpStartupInfo` parameter can point to either a `STARTUPINFO` *or* `STARTUPINFOEX` structure, where the latter had additional members appended in Vista. `CreateProcess` can distinguish between the two by looking at the `STARTUPINFO::cb` size. If the `struct` were passed by value, instead, then such a change would have been binary incompatible with the pre-Vista `CreateProcess` and would have required adding a separate API, instead.

Comment: `startup_info`: is there some Handle to close ? `hStdInput`, `hStdOutput`, and `hStdError` if `STARTF_USESTDHANDLES` is specified (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686331(v=vs.85).aspx) ?